# Intellij IDEA setting for "method call argument:s chop down if long" misbehaving

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings, formatter, chop

Whenever I call a method that has too many arguments and the line exceeds the margin, I need it to put each of the params on separate lines.

My settings:
[image: My settings]

Original code:

```
return getSubscriptionList(contractNumber, objects, acceptLanguage, userNumber, bankSystem, groupIdentification).stream()
        .map(subscription -> createSubscriptionListItem(subscription,accountsFilterItems))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After reformatting (this changes it exactly to what I want):

```
return getSubscriptionList(
        contractNumber,
        objects,
        acceptLanguage,
        userNumber,
        bankSystem,
        groupIdentification
).stream()
        .map(subscription -> createSubscriptionListItem(subscription, accountsFilterItems))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After reformatting the already reformatted code again:

```
return getSubscriptionList(contractNumber,
        objects,
        acceptLanguage,
        userNumber,
        bankSystem,
        groupIdentification
).stream()
        .map(subscription -> createSubscriptionListItem(subscription, accountsFilterItems))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Why does it change the format the second time, and how can I change my settings to fix it?

[Link to settings XML export](https://pastebin.com/tbMtrrkz)

Comment: Please report it as a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, created as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280244 for anyone who might be looking for a resolution as well